# Running java file on windows cmd CLI. : Error : cannot find symbol

Tags: java, command-line

My PC is running windows 7. I have three java files on the SAME folder in location C:\Users\L33604\Desktop\Java Files. One of the java file called DataLogger.java calls two other classes as in creating 2 java objects. The 2 other classes are found in CustomWiresharkLogFormatter.java and TextFileReader.java.

I managed to compile the CustomWiresharkLogFormatter.java and TextFileReader.java by entering javac CustomWiresharkLogFormatter.java and javac TextFileReader.java through he windows command line interface and the class files for the 2 classes are created in the same folder. However, i cannot compile the DataLogger.java successfully. I saw this error when i attempt to enter javac DataLogger.java on the win cmd cli. I can run these 3 files using the eclipse ide.

ERROR seen in the windows command line interface:

DataLogger.java :18 error: cannot find symbol.

//this is a line in DataLogger.java String [] unLoggedTextLineArr = new TextFileReader().readTsharkTxtFile();

Symbol class : TextFileReader

Location class : DataLogger

//This is a line in DataLogger.java DataLogger.java :28 error: cannot find symbol.

String [] unLoggedTextLineArr = fileHandler.setFormatter(new CustomWiresharkLogFormatter());

Symbol class : CustomWiresharkLogFormatter

Location class : DataLogger

Symbol : class CustomWiresharkLogFormatter

class TextFileReader

2 errors.

How to i make sure that i can run the DataLogger java file that creates the 2 java objects from the other 2 java files using the windows command line interface commands??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your classpath to the path where your class files are located.

Comment: i set the the current working directory in the windows command line to the folder where the class files are found. i entered set CLASSPATH = TextFileReader.class; CustomWiresharkLogFormatter.class then i entered javac DataLogger.java . The same error appears

Comment: use something like this...set classpath = folder location

Comment: Say for instance my class files are in folder shashank, then set the class path as .....set classpath=d:/Shashank

Comment: I enetered : set CLASSPATH = "C:\\Users\\L33604\\Desktop\\Runner" . All the java files and the class files are found in the same folder directory i mentioned above. It is still not working

Comment: Try this...set CLASSPATH =C:\Users\L33604\Desktop\Runner